# Karma Jasmin-core missing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am doing unit testing of Angular JS using Karma and Jasmine.

I followed steps mentioned in following url:

http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/08/03/angularjs-unit-testing-tutorial-karma-jasmine/

I followed every step. But when i tried command :`karma start`, i got error saying  `Cannot find module 'jasmine-core'`, but when i checked in folder, jasmine-core module is present.

Please help.

Comment: have you installed karma-cli? and check if your node version is compatible with the karma version

Comment: My node version is compatible. How can i install karma-cli ?

Comment: npm install -g karma-cli

Comment: Thanx. It worked... :)